# Visual Studio Hotkeys not working properly

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

edit: it seems that for VS the \ I enter via regular keyboard does not equal to \ that I enter over the onscreen keyboard. I hope this image demonstrates my issue somewhat:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xh5vo.png

I'm somewhat new to VS and was trying to get used to hotkeys.
After a while some of the hotkeys (like Ctrl + ` and Ctrl + \ ) stopped working.
Other basic hotkeys (like Ctrl + S and Ctrl + Z) still work fine.

I tried resetting hotkeys, resetting settings and reinstalling VS but it didn't help.
I don't have a lock fn function on my keyboard. 
The program itself is in english, system locale is english and the input is english as well.

I'm sorry to ask this kind of question but I've searched everything and spent about 4 hours trying to figure out what is wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any additional extensions installed overriding the default behavior?

Comment: Make sure it's not a problem of confusing `Ctrl+Key1, Ctrl+Key2` with `Ctrl+Key1, Key2`. If you assign `Ctrl + \` to something (without a second key afterwards), does that also not work? Do you get that "waiting for second key" message in the status bar?

Comment: thanks for the suggestions
@ForeverZer0 i tried using it on a clean install after restart, no change.


Andrew yes, I'm not confusing those. I tried assigning those and they work like brand new hotkeys completely separate from the regular hotkeys.

I fixed the problem for the "\" by using the EN_GB keyboard instead of EN_US (tried both normal one and international layout)

Comment: If you have a number pad on your keyboard, does it work with the `/` on that? I don't know if VS differentiates between the two, just throwing out something to possibly try and track this down.

Comment: The ` is still problematic and the onscreen keyboard won't let me type (and test) it because it's a not common enough character to be included there.

Comment: @ForeverZer0 yes it does differentiate https://i.imgur.com/v9FnK2K.png